# Change the value of NSString, am I doing it right?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a class as follows

```
@interface sampleClass: UIViewController
{
    NSString *currentLocation;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *currentLocation;
```

So, whenever the current GPS changes, a function will be called as follows:

```
-(void)newLocationUpdate:(NSString *)text {
  NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:text];
  currentGPS = temp;
  [temp release];
}
```

I am wondering if I am doing it right? Thanks.

Comment: The class `@interface` and the method you posted don't seem to interrelate. I think you need to clarify a bit what you're asking. What do you want to do?

Comment: why have you chosen copy instead of retain?

Comment: @DysonApps: For classes that implement `copy`, it's probably the correct choice for a property of that type. The reason is that if a class lets you copy it, that means it *could* be mutable (otherwise there's no point in copying). If you just `retain` a mutable object, other owners can mutate it without your knowledge or consent. So you almost always want to use `copy` if you have the choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the `currentLocation`/`currentGPS` confusion — no, that's still not quite right.

You don't show the the setter for `currentLocation`. I'll assume it's a `@synthesize`d property. If you just write `currentLocation = something`, you're not invoking the property setter; you're just setting the instance variable. This means that after you release the object in the very next line, your instance variable is probably pointing to a deallocated object.

The correct way to write it (again, assuming you have a synthesized accessor) would be:

```
-(void)newLocationUpdate:(NSString *)text {
  self.currentLocation = text;
}
```

This invokes the property accessor, which copies the object for you.

If for some reason you *needed* to access the instance variable directly (like if this *were* the setter method for `currentLocation`), you would write:

```
-(void)newLocationUpdate:(NSString *)text {
  [currentLocation release];
  currentLocation = [temp copy];
}
```

Comment: Hi Chuck, thanks for the answer,what do you mean by "If for some reason you needed to access the instance variable directly" ? Thanks.

Comment: @nababa: `currentLocation` is both an instance variable and a property. The instance variable is where the value is stored, while the property defines how you access the instance variable. A synthesized property creates methods to handle things like making sure to release the old object and copy the new one when you assign through it. When you write `self.currentLocation`, you're going through the property accessor. When you write `currentLocation` (notice no `self.`), you're accessing the instance variable directly, without going through the property accessor.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your `currentLocation`/`currentGPS` setter implemented properly (with `@synthesize` or a manual implementation), then you're doing too much work. If you have a property declared with the `copy` flag, as you do, then the setter method itself will do the copy that you're doing by hand. All you would need is this line:

```
[self setCurrentGPS:text];
```

Or, if you prefer the property syntax:

```
self.currentGPS = text;
```

That will automatically call the `copy` method, which is basically a more efficient way of doing what you're doing the long way with `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:text]`.

Comment: @aryaxt: Somebody went through and downvoted all the answers to this question except Matt S's. I don't know why they did it — at least three of the answers were correct (counting this one), and Matt's is borderline wrong (I say borderline only because the answer acknowledges that it's incorrect). I upvoted Kubi's to balance it out but I guess I missed this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
@interface sampleClass: UIViewController
{
NSString *currentLocation;
}
 -(void)newLocationUpdate:(NSString *)text;
```

.m

```
-(void)newLocationUpdate:(NSString *)text {
  currentLocation = text; 
}
```

That's the way I would do it.  Is it correct? Probably not.  Will it work? Yes.

Comment: It will work until your app crashes because you're managing memory wrong.

Comment: @Chuck, yea, that happened to me a few times (simple retain fixed it, hacky, I know).  The way I posted isn't the best, but it'll get the job done (for a while)

Answer (score -1):

Nope, you're doing it wrong.

Your class `sampleClass` has an ivar named `currentLocation` and a property named `currentLocation`. In your `newLocationUpdate` method you are setting a variable named `currentGPS` to the string value passed to that method. As written, `currentGPS` has no relationship with either the variable `currentLocation` or the property `currentLocation`.

Also, your use of `init` and `release` in your `newLocationUpdate` method looks like you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of how memory management in Obj-C works. You should definitely read Apple's guidelines on memory management.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

This is important stuff! Good luck.